# Where is degree freedom correction coming from in causal inference variance estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, causality

This is related to Theorem 7.1 of Rubin's Causal Inference on page 122. In comparison to variance estimator on page 125, I do not see $N-1-dim(X_i)$ correction coming from.

Consider completely randomized trial in a sample of size $N$ drawn from infinite population. Let $Y_i^{obs}$ be observed random variable of $i-$th subject with $W_i=0,1$ for treatment and control group. Set $X_i$ pre-treatment covariates. Consider model $Y_i^{obs}=\alpha+\tau W_i+\beta X_i+e_i$ where $e_i$ is error.

Let $\tau_{sp}$ be superpopulation treatment effect and $\tau^\star,\alpha^\star,\beta^\star$ be corresponding minimizer of $E[(Y_i^{obs}-\alpha-\tau W_i-\beta X_i)^2]$ for $\alpha,\tau,\beta$. Let $\alpha_{ols},\beta_{ols},\tau_{ols}$ be ordinary least square estimate of one particular realization. Then by theorem 7.1 $\sqrt{N}(\tau_{ols}-\tau_{sp})\sim Normal(0,\frac{E[(W_i-p)^2(Y_i^{obs}-\alpha^\star-\tau_{sp})^2]}{p^2(1-p)^2})$ where $p$ is number of treated subjects.

The variance estimator of $\tau_{ols}$ on page 125 is given as the following.

Hetero case: $V_{sp}=\frac{1}{N(N-1-dim(X))}\frac{\sum_i(W_i-\bar{W})^2(Y_i^{obs}-\alpha_{ols}-\tau_{ols}W_i-X_i\beta_{ols})^2}{\bar{W}^2(1-\bar{W})^2}$.

Homo case: $V_{sp}=\frac{1}{N(N-1-dim(X))}\frac{\sum_i(Y_i^{obs}-\alpha_{ols}-\tau_{ols}W_i-X_i\beta_{ols})^2}{\bar{W}(1-\bar{W})}$.

From $\frac{E[(W_i-p)^2(Y_i^{obs}-\alpha^\star-\tau_{sp})^2]}{p^2(1-p)^2}$, I would expect $\frac{1}{N^2}$ for both expressions instead of $\frac{1}{N(N-1-dim(X_i))}$.

Where is $\frac{1}{N-1-dim(X_i)}$ coming from? Talking about true model residual does not make too much sense to me as the model needs not be correctly specified at all. In particular, I think standard variance estimation argument by tracing over idempotent matrix is not correct here as model is possibly misspecified.